# Vowpal Wabbit IO Throughput?

Tags: r, machine-learning, io, classification, vowpalwabbit

I'm trying to build a model for a classification problem using `vw`, The problem is that when I run this code to get the predictions:

```
vw -t -i model.vw -p predictions.txt test.txt
```

It takes ages for the `predictions.txt` to be written down to the file-system(about 50 minutes for a test with 10 millions of samples); I thought using an SSD disc drive instead of a magnetic one may speed up the process but it didn't make much differences, I also tried different file-systems(NTFS, XFS and EXT4) and it also didn't help much too; I thought `vw` would have an option to buffer the output before writing it out but I could't find it.

Any suggestion on this issue?

**Additional info**:

`vw` version is 8.5.0 built from source(from Github.com repo of course) on Debian 9 AMD64. Read/Write is done on a partition with NTFS as its file-system(on a magnetic HDD). `cat` has a throughput between 20MB to 30MB writing to a file on this partition.

It seems when I start `vw` it spawns another child process that is somewhat slower.

General process state info:

```
PID PRI NI  VIRT    RES SHR S   CPU%    MEM%    TIME+   Command
3943    20  0   1131M   85728   6196    S   73.3    1.7 9:32.03 ├─ vw -t -i models/model.vw.30 -p x.txt
3944    20  0   1131M   85728   6196    R   36.3    1.7 4:53.39 │  └─ vw
```

Sample `strace` output for the parent process:

```
Trace of process 3943 - vw -t -i models/model.vw.30 -p x.txt
strace: Process 3943 attached
futex(0x561432250dfc, FUTEX_WAKE_OP_PRIVATE, 1, 1, 0x561432250df8, FUTEX_OP_SET<<28|0<<12|FUTEX_OP_CMP_GT<<24|0x1) = 1
futex(0x561432250da0, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
write(4, "0.131190\n", 9)               = 9
futex(0x561432250dfc, FUTEX_WAKE_OP_PRIVATE, 1, 1, 0x561432250df8, FUTEX_OP_SET<<28|0<<12|FUTEX_OP_CMP_GT<<24|0x1) = 1
futex(0x561432250da0, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
write(4, "0.149736\n", 9)               = 9
futex(0x561432250dfc, FUTEX_WAKE_OP_PRIVATE, 1, 1, 0x561432250df8, FUTEX_OP_SET<<28|0<<12|FUTEX_OP_CMP_GT<<24|0x1) = 1
futex(0x561432250da0, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
write(4, "0.287871\n", 9)               = 9
futex(0x561432250dfc, FUTEX_WAKE_OP_PRIVATE, 1, 1, 0x561432250df8, FUTEX_OP_SET<<28|0<<12|FUTEX_OP_CMP_GT<<24|0x1) = 1
futex(0x561432250da0, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
write(4, "0.133941\n", 9)               = 9
futex(0x561432250dfc, FUTEX_WAKE_OP_PRIVATE, 1, 1, 0x561432250df8, FUTEX_OP_SET<<28|0<<12|FUTEX_OP_CMP_GT<<24|0x1) = 1
futex(0x561432250da0, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
write(4, "0.141326\n", 9)               = 9
futex(0x561432250dfc, FUTEX_WAKE_OP_PRIVATE, 1, 1, 0x561432250df8, FUTEX_OP_SET<<28|0<<12|FUTEX_OP_CMP_GT<<24|0x1) = 1
futex(0x561432250da0, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
write(4, "0.107144\n", 9)               = 9
futex(0x561432250dfc, FUTEX_WAKE_OP_PRIVATE, 1, 1, 0x561432250df8, FUTEX_OP_SET<<28|0<<12|FUTEX_OP_CMP_GT<<24|0x1) = 1
futex(0x561432250da0, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
write(4, "0.395839\n", 9)               = 9
futex(0x561432250dfc, FUTEX_WAKE_OP_PRIVATE, 1, 1, 0x561432250df8, FUTEX_OP_SET<<28|0<<12|FUTEX_OP_CMP_GT<<24|0x1) = 1
```

Sample `strace` output for the child process:

```
Trace of process 3944 - vw
strace: Process 3944 attached
futex(0x561432250da0, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
futex(0x561432250dfc, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 5046163, NULL) = 0
futex(0x561432250da0, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
futex(0x561432250dfc, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 5046165, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
futex(0x561432250da0, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
futex(0x561432250dfc, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 5046167, NULL) = 0
futex(0x561432250da0, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
futex(0x561432250dfc, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 5046169, NULL) = 0
futex(0x561432250da0, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
futex(0x561432250dfc, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 5046171, NULL) = 0
futex(0x561432250da0, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
futex(0x561432250dfc, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 5046173, NULL) = 0
futex(0x561432250da0, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
read(0, "1 |a x:5646322 |b 5646322 |c uBy"..., 5977) = 5977
futex(0x561432250dfc, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 5046175, NULL) = 0
futex(0x561432250da0, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
futex(0x561432250da0, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
read(0, "23:25.0 I24:25.0 I25:23.0 I26:25"..., 64944) = 56380
futex(0x561432250dfc, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 5046177, NULL) = 0
futex(0x561432250da0, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
futex(0x561432250dfc, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 5046179, NULL) = 0
futex(0x561432250da0, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
futex(0x561432250dfc, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 5046181, NULL) = 0
futex(0x561432250da0, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
futex(0x561432250dfc, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 5046183, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
futex(0x561432250da0, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
```

Comment: 50 min sounds long, but if your examples are very large, it may be possible.  `vw` should be roughly ~4-5x slower than a straight `cat` of the same data. What's your throughput in MB per second? When I run `vw` on my desktop I get amortized throughput of roughly ~40MB per second.

Comment: Wow, around 40MB write per second?, I have it a round 400KB a second. I suspect ```vw``` line-buffers the output before writing it out line by line but I'm not sure about it, and yes my examples are quite big.

Comment: More information would help. The question has not enough detail to try and reproduce.  Did you measure throughput of `cat` on same data? I suspect you have an issue with underlying IO (hardware, OS, disk, or network) not with `vw`.  You can also `strace` the process and see where it hangs or becoming slow.  Lastly: is the `vw` process running stand-alone like in the command line above or is it piping/feeding into another much slower process?